# c++ QT and OpenCV. setMouseCallBack in QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm using the function setMouseCallback to extract the information about pixel coordinates at every mouse event. The program I created works perfectly if I use openCV windows. Precisely:

image is cv::Mat;

```
cv::namedWindow("Original", WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("Original", image);

cv::setMouseCallback("Original", mouseWrapper, NULL);
```

where

```
void esempio::onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
//---------------------------------------------------------
// Code to read the mouse event in the identification of a point
//---------------------------------------------------------
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            std::cout << "1: " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
            pp_m.x=x;
            pp_m.y=y;
        }
}

void mouseWrapper( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
{
    esempio * mainWin = (esempio *)(param);
    mainWin->onMouse(event,x,y,flags,0);
}
```

Now, I would like to use the same code in a QLabel created in my interface. I tried to use the function setWindowTitle to change the name of the QLabel in this way:

```
ui->label_show->setWindowTitle("Test");
cv::setMouseCallback("Test", mouseWrapper, NULL);
```

but this approach seems not adequate.

How can I indicate to the function setMouseCallback to work on the desired QLabel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be hard because:

- I'm not sure that the OS is taking into account titles of child widgets, and I'm not sure that OpenCV will recognize window title of a non-top-level widget;
- Qt handles child widgets internally and doesn't expose them to OS unless forced to do that;
- Most importantly, OpenCV won't have a chance to call your callback because Qt manages the event loop.

I don't see why not use Qt's own means to react on mouse events.

Call `ui->label_show->installEventFilter(this)` in constructor of your form and implement virtual `eventFilter` function. In this function you can use `event` argument to retrieve event type and mouse coordinates (after casting to `QMouseEvent`).

See [event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).

Comment: I read about event filters, but I would like just to know to adapt my function to QLabel. I'll move to Qt events! thanks